# CSS :hover Selector does not change colour

Tags: html, css, hover

I am new to CSS, so please don't bite my head off here for something very simple. Basically, I am trying to change the color of a uni code character when hovering the cursor over it, but it does not seem to be working.

Current Code:

```css
.fa:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="google-circle">
  <a href="www.google.com" class="fa fa-google" style="font-size: 19px; color: white; margin-left: 7px; margin-top: 5.5px; text-decoration: none;"></a>
</div>
```

Could someone please, kindly, tell me what I am doing wrong, along with some better advice on how to avoid common CSS mistakes, or if this is bad practice. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are defining the color to white in your HTML with inline CSS. Inline styling takes precedence over external stylesheets, so your CSS is ignored. Move the CSS from the HTML document to your external CSS file.

```css
body {
  background-color: #C2C2C2;
}

.fa {
  font-size: 19px; 
  color: white; 
  margin-left: 7px; 
  margin-top: 5.5px; 
  text-decoration: none;
}

.fa:hover{
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="google-circle">
  <a href="www.google.com" class="fa fa-google" style=""></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I fixed it...sorry for any inconvenience caused, but thank you very much! And a big thanks for the help.